# ng-repeat is not working for options

Tags: angularjs

In my project I am looking to fill the options for select using AngularJS, but it's not working for options tag where it is working fine for ul tag.

Controller code

```
$scope.courses = ["Maths","Science","History","English","IT"];
```

Code in view

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="chosen-select">
    <option ng-repeat="course in courses" value="course">{{course}}</option>
    <!-- <option ng-options="course in courses">{{course}}</option> -->
  </select>    
</div>
```

Preview of the output
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and try using `ng-options` on `<select>` instead

Comment: Also note it [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kxR2KnQOfIyaNiwhXDVJ?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl I edited the question, is it enough for you to answer

Comment: Apart from hard coded value it works fine. Explain problem in more detail and modify demo above to reproduce whatever problem you have

Comment: ya problem is with the "chosen-select" class, but y a css class is impacting angular?

Comment: Are you using a *"chosen"* plugin? You haven't provided enough detail to show why it would not work or exactly how it  isn't working

Comment: when I remove the chosen class it works as i expect, with choosen plugin i cannot do anything in javascript. is there a way to fix it.

Comment: Where is your demo that reproduces problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because you made some errors on controller side.

Anyways, this is a [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2DOYdzFQQ1Qubn1TWNt) which reproduces your situation.

**JS:**

```
angular.module("myApp", []);

//Pattern to avoid minification problems
angular.module("myApp").controller("MyController", MyController);

MyController.$inject = []; //Your dependencies between "" go here

function MyController(){ //Your dependencies go here

  var vm = this;

  vm.courses = ["Maths","Science","History","English","IT"];

}
```

**Html:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  . . .
  <body ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <select >
      <option ng-repeat="course in myCtrl.courses" value="course">{{course}}</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output

[image]

I'm using the `controllerAs` syntax. You can dig in to that syntax [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController).

Hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> This sample show to you have can use select by 2 way **ngRepeat** and **ngOptions**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

  $scope.courses = ["Maths","Science","History","English","IT"];
  
})
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <h1>with ng-option</h1>
   <select ng-model="test1" ng-options="course for course in courses"  class="chosen-select">
  </select>
  {{test1}}
  
    <h1>with ng-repeat</h1>
   <select ng-model="test2" class="chosen-select">
     <option ng-repeat="course in courses" ng-value="course">
       {{course}}
     </option>
  </select>
  {{test2}}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</div>
```